# Add proxy to all network traffic of another adapter

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

In my PC I have 2 network adapters. My Xbox is connected to my PC and my PC to router:

```
Xbox ====> PC =====> Router (Modem)
```

So in `Network Connections` in Control Panel, I can see 2 adapters: `Ethernet` (Router) and `Ethernet2` (Xbox).

Now, I want to add a proxy to **all the traffic of my Xbox** (TCP would be enough though). Currently I use Proxifier to handle the traffic of specific programs in my Windows machine and it's working perfectly. I'm not familiar with any particular program that can capture the connections from `Ethernet2` and let me add a rule to Proxifier which says "add a proxy to all the traffic from that program".

Note: I'm familiar with the ICS which lets me connect to a VPN, right click on a VPN connection, go to Sharing and select "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection". But unfortunately I don't have access to a VPN proxy and where I live, this is not easily accessible due to limitations on PPTP and L2TP connections.

Comment: If you just want to analyze xbox traffic you can run wireshark on interface between xbox and pc

Comment: @AEonAX No I'm not looking to just sniff the traffic. I want to interfere. I want to add a proxy server in the middle to pass all the traffic through that proxy to the Xbox.